# pandas: for loop to merge on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, merge

I have two dataframes which I am trying to combine. The first dataset had agents IDs and multiple columns with skills assigned to each agent.

df1:

| Login ID | Skill Assignment 1 | Skill Assignment 2 | Skill Assignment 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000. | 500 | 7008. | 1655. |
| 1001. | 2590. | 3846. | 3847. |
| 1002. | 500. | 2226. | . |

The second dataframe has call volume information split by agent and skill.

df2:

| Logid. | Skill | Call Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000. | 500. | 150. |
| 1000. | 7008. | 54. |
| 1000. | 1655. | 70. |
| 1001. | 2590. | 30. |
| 1001. | 3846. | 240. |
| 1001. | 3847. | 120. |
| 1002. | 500 | 230. |
| 1002. | 2226. | 45. |

I am trying to add call volume to each agents & skill assignment using for loop, the df has 120 columns, to create new df with skill assignments and call volumes:

df3:

| Login ID | Skill Assignment 1 | Call Volume 1 | Skill Assignment 2 | Call Volume 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000. | 500 | 150. | 7008. | 54. |
| 1001. | 2590. | 30. | 3846. | 240. |
| 1002. | 500. | 230. | 2226. | 45. |

I am trying to merge the two datasets and rename the Call Volume column each time is added on:

```
for i in number_list:
 df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = [df1['Login ID'], df1['Skill Assignment ' +str(i)]], right_on = ['Logid', 'Skill'])
 df3.rename({'Call Volume' : 'Call Volume ' + str(i)}, axis = 1, inplace = True).drop(['Logid', 'Skill'], axis = 1)
```

When the code runs it keeps only the 120 column. Is there a way to keep each column or more adequate way to add the Call Volumes to each skill?

Comment: What's up with the strange dot after each number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the '.' character that appears in df1 and df2 is not there,

I think what you're looking for is something along these lines, using `melt`:

```
df1_melt=pd.melt(df1,id_vars='Login ID', value_name='Skill', var_name='Skill Assignment')
df3=df2.merge(df1_melt, left_on=['Logid.','Skill'], right_on=['Login ID','Skill'], how='left').drop('Logid.', axis=1)
```

I believe df3 is the relationship you're looking for.  If further grouping is necessary, you can use pivot:

```
df_pivot=df3.pivot_table(index=['Login ID'], columns=['Skill'], values=['Call Volume','Skill Assignment'] )
```

---